# How to know on which column an index is set [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute an insert statement, I get the following error message:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MY_TABLE' with unique
>   index 'MY_INDEX'. The duplicate key value is ().

However, I'm trying to insert a date with an ID that doesn't exist in the table, so I would like to know on which column this index is set to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "object explorer"
navigate to your database, and then to your table
expand the table (click the little plus sign)
expand the folder "indexes"
right-click the index in question
click "script index as..."
click "create to..."
click "clipboard"

paste this index create query in a new window and you'll see exactly what the index does.

Alternatively, you can write the following query and see the results in the index section:
`SP_HELP <my table>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON when you want to insert a value into a table with an ID column. Even when you pass an ID it will try to create one. EX:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourdb.yourschema.yourtable ON

[INSERT statement here]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourdb.yourschema.yourtable OFF
```

To check your Table dependencies for keys you can right click on your table and go to View Dependencies.

Comment: I tried your solution and I still get the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

In query editor, select the table name and press `Alt F1`. You can see the index under index name.

Answer (score 0):

To go along with @jacob H's answer if you want to still view index information.

To view table indexes, expand your table in the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio and then expand the "Indexes" subfolder to see what indexes are on your table.  You can right click the index and "Script index as > Create > new query editor window".  This will show you exactly what columns it is on.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the table name and press ALT + F1 it shows you a list of indexes and the name of the column (index keys).

Example:

index_name      index_description               **index_keys**
IX_D_Pessoa_CPF nonclustered located on PRIMARY **CPF**